# How to add GZIP compression to my project (hosted on aws, running apache server)

Tags: javascript, apache, amazon-web-services, gzip, httpd.conf

I am trying to gzip the data returned from my app.

I'm Using
Server version: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix)
Architecture:   64-bit

First I follow instructions here

```
.htaccess
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
   mod_gzip_on Yes
   mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
   mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
   mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
   mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
   mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
   mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
   mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

and then

```
httpd.conf 
#
# AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
# information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
# Despite the name similarity, the following Add* directives have nothing
# to do with the FancyIndexing customization directives above.
#
AddEncoding x-compress .Z
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz

# If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
# probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
#
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
```

Then I want to make sure I am testing it right.
I paste the url to my site to sites like this
[Check GZIP compression](http://checkgzipcompression.com/)
and I see that my site is not gzipped.

Then I use Chrome dev tool view (last request row) to see that the size and the content is not the same

[Chrome dev tool view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKWxE.png)

This looks like the content and the size are different?
is it GZipped

Questions:

1. When do I update htaaccess and when httpd.conf
2. What is the correct way to verify my transported data is compressed?